# WordPress is removing query variables like page, p from the URL of a custom static page

Tags: php, query, urls, variables

I am working on a custom template and displaying some posts (of custom type) teasers on it. In the template PHP file, I want to retrieve a URL query variable (if passed) and display the content accordingly. The URL with the query variable is generated from the same template page. If I try something like this to generate URL:

```
<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'custom_var', '2' ) ); ?>
```

and in functions.php:

```
function add_custom_query_var($vars) {
    $vars[] = "custom_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var');
```

and go to `http://www.example.com/template_page_url/?custom_var=xyz`, it work as expected and I can get the value using `get_query_var` function. The problem is that when I replace this `custom_var` with `page` or `p`, these variables are removed from the URL automatically when the page is loaded. In short a URL like:

`http://www.example.com/template_page_url/?page=xyz` is redirected to:

`http://www.example.com/template_page_url/`

Can we not use these variables in custom templates? Or is there any way to do so? And I am not looking for pagination, this `page` variable is meant for totally custom logic. I know the `WP_Query` class also use `page` variable and I am sure there is something conflicting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the `/template_page_url/` will be rewritten to something like `?page=template_page_url` and if you then add your own `page` query parameter then this will of course get lost during this phase.

Comment: `page` and `p` are reserved terms, you basically can’t use them. You’ll need to come up with something else.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Yes, it seems I have to compromise and use some other query var name.